# RestEasy Client Authentication and HTTP Put with Marshalling

Tags: http-post, marshalling, jax-rs, resteasy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to test my  REST-Service using the RestEasy Client Framework. 
In my application I am using Basic Authentication. According to the RestEasy documentation I am using the `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient` to set the Credentials for Authentication.

For an HTTP-GET Request this works fine, I am authorized and I get the result Response which I wanted.

But what if I want to make a HTTP-Post/HTTP-Put with an Java Object (in XML) in the HTTP-Body of the Request? Is there a way to automatically marshall the Java Object into the HTTP-Body when I am using the `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient`?

Here's my code for authentication, can someone tell me how to make an HTTP-Post/HTTP-Put without writing an XML-String or using an InputStream?

```
@Test
public void testClient() throws Exception {

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                        new AuthScope(host, port),
                        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        ApacheHttpClient4Executor executer = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(
                        client);
        ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(requestUrl, executer);
        request.accept("*/*").pathParameter("param", requestParam);

        // This works fine   
        ClientResponse<MyClass> response = request
                        .get(MyClass.class);
        assertTrue(response.getStatus() == 200);

        // What if i want to make the following instead:
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.setName("AJKL");
        // TODO Marshall this in the HTTP Body => call method 


}
```

Is there maybe a possibillity to use the Server-side Mock Framework and then marshall and send my object there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ok, got it working, thats my new code:**

```
@Test
public void testClient() throws Exception {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(host, port),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
    ApacheHttpClient4Executor executer = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(
                    client);


    RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());

    Employee employee= new Employee();
    employee.setName("AJKL");

    EmployeeResource employeeResource= ProxyFactory.create(
            EmployeeResource.class, restServletUrl, executer);

    Response response  = employeeResource.createEmployee(employee);

}
```

**EmployeeResource :**

```
@Path("/employee")
public interface EmployeeResource {

    @PUT
    @Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    void createEmployee(Employee employee);

 }
```

Comment: Hi Joshi, could you please post how your MyResourceClass looks like?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I updated my code to show you the MyResourceClass, now named EmployeeResource!